# Cabal IPPrint package fails to build

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I am trying to get [this coloured ghci prompt](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/) to work.  I am getting the following error which I suspect is due to cabal not updating the right package. Anyone has any idea?

```
; cabal install IPPrint 
[...]
System/Unix/Chroot.hs:23:49:
    Module `System.Process' does not export `showCommandForUser'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Extra-1.42 depends on Unixutils-1.52 which failed to install.
Unixutils-1.52 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
ipprint-0.4.1 depends on Unixutils-1.52 which failed to install.
```

The prompt should look like this:

[image: haskell ghci colour prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`showCommandForUser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.1.0.1/doc/html/System-Process.html#v%3ashowCommandForUser) was added in version 1.1 of the [`process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) package. You need ghc-7.2 or later to have that (process is one of the boot packages, installing a version other than that came with GHC is not recommended unless you know very well what you are doing; reinstalling boot packages is likely to cause breakage among the installed packages).

If you have an older GHC, upgrading GHC is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Ah, it would be nice to have a package for Fedora 16 that was not old. Meh.

Comment: Is there no ghc package with a newer GHC than 7.0 for Fedora? Even if not, you can install a vanilla binary (may be problematic if the gmp versions don't match) or build one from source. Building from source takes a while, but you don't need to do that too often.

Comment: The [justhub](http://www.justhub.org/) distribution does have an up to date version of both ghc and the Haskell Platform.  There are normal up to date packages but F16 is a little old now in release Fedora terms.

Comment: Meh, even with that more failures.  I give up.

Comment: What failures? And what is the "that" in "even with that"? It may not be too bad.

Comment: `cabal install IPPrint 'Extra > 1.45'` was the thing I was missing.  Without forcing the package, I got Extra 1.42 which gives me errors. Got there! Thanks.